# NSArrayController, View Based Table, NSPopUpButton and Bindings

Tags: macos, xcode8, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, nspopupbutton

I am trying to bind a `NSPopUpButton` in a view based `NSTableView` with `NSArrayContollers` using Xcode 8.1.  I have an macOS app that had been using a cell based `NSTableView` and I would like to convert it to a view based table, however, I have been completely unsuccessful in doing this.  I have looked at all the various wed postings, but nothing seems to work for me.  I have been working on this for over two days.

Here is my design:
`accountArrayController` is bound to the larger table and this all seems to work just fine.
`patientArrayController` is a`NSMutableArray` of `NSString`'s that contains the list of patients to be populated in the menu items of the `NSPopUpButton`.

Here are the actual bindings for the `NSPopUpButton`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am guessing that the problem is in the `Content Values` bindings, I have tried many variations.  When I compile this, I get

> .../xxx.storyboard: Exception while running ibtool: *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

However, when I try other variations, Xcode (really ibtool) hangs for a long time and then exits with an error code of 255.

How can I resolve this? I'm happy to provide other binding information and code blocks, if needed.

Answer (score -1):

The model attribute name you used in the NSTableColumn bind, you want to *also* use in the Table Cell View bind - **3rd** level down from table column. It should have filled in already 'objectValue' or 'selection' or 'arrangedObjects', just add . and you should be good.